# Can we install Greengrass core for different platform other than Linux?

Tags: aws-iot, aws-greengrass

I'm new to AWS Greengrass and at the phase of learning it functionalities.

As instructed in AWS Greengrass, when creating a new group we need to establish a Greengrass core in the cloud definition for a group.

Every group needs a 'Greengrass core' to function. Adding a core to a cloud definition of a group represents a physical device.

So this means 'Greengrass core' software has to be installed in one of my physical devices. According to the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-setup.html), it says that

> "Where platform is either: linux-armv7l, linux-x86-64, linux-aarch64

I want to know whether anyone has tried this on macOS?

Comment: I found almost the same information from https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/06/aws-greengrass so no ios no windows

Answer (score 1):

You could have answered this yourself merely by reading the extensive [documentation of the required Linux configuration](https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/faqs/) : No.

This is likely because key parts of the core are provided only as precompiled binaries.

While it's likely these proprietary components could be ported to OSX by Amazon, there's little reason to do so since there isn't much in the way of OSX hardware economically suited to this role.

I don't immediately see anything that would prevent a developer wishing to experiment from running this inside a Linux virtual machine hosted on OSX, which is already the normal course for many doing embedded Linux development.

(Or you could run Linux natively on the Mac... but that hardly counts for your question)

Note that the IoT device *client* SDK is portable.